# Field "account"&"card" is never assigned to, and will default Null

Tags: c#

The error says that the card and account fields are never assigned to, but they are assigned to in the default constructor. Am i missing something here?

```
    private string firstName, lastName;
    private string address, number;
    private Account account;
    private Card card;

    public Person()
    {
        firstName = "John";
        lastName = "Doe";
        address = "";
        number = "02080000000";
        account.AccountNumber = "0000";
        card.CardNumber = "0000/0000/0000/0000";
        card.PinNumber = "0000";
    }

    public Person(string FName, string LName, string Address, string Number, string AccNumber, string CardNumber, string PinNumber)
    {
        firstName = FName;
        lastName = LName;
        address = Address;
        number = Number;
        account.AccountNumber = AccNumber;
        card.CardNumber = CardNumber;
        card.PinNumber = PinNumber;
    }
```

Comment: `card.CardNumber = CardNumber;` is not an assignment to `card`. It is an assignment to *a property of* `card`. If you assign nothing to `card` itself, it will remain null, and trying to assign values to its properties will not end well. You should also consider using standard .NET naming conventions.

Answer (score 6):

You first need to *create* them, and only then assign values to their properties.

```
private Account account = new Account();
private Card card = new Card();
```